# how to use ajax synchronize function without refresh function in few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I want to display the contents of the mysql database with the ajax function. is it possible to make the ajax function "synchron" with mysql database, without "auto_refresh" to ajax function in the next few seconds.

if the function is available. I want to apply it to my "messenger app", in terms of displaying new messages available, without performing the "refresh ajax" function once every 1 second

Comment: Where is your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web pages are a Stateless communication system. There is NO link between the server and browser except a "request->receipt" where the browser says "gimme" and the server says "k, here". After that the link is broken.

What this means is that NO, you can not get a signal in a web page without requesting the information (ie every second or some other interval) unless you use a workaround (which will, invariably, still require that workaround system to send and receive a signal at necessary intervals).

If you can install an app on the workstation, that's a different story. That app could then listen on a specific port (assigned through the client's firewall) and you're all set since the server can be informed of the firewall port and send the packet accordingly. But web browsers only check for and receive data after sending data at present.

That being said, there are plenty of messenger apps out there which utilize javascript/ajax methods to accomplish this task. By polling, with tiny packets. (such as those mentioned by Kishor Malakar)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for real time updates from the server, look into `socket.io` in `node.js`. Otherwise you will have to keep checking for updates in interval. That wouldn't be a very good idea.